# Two separated divs with 100% width not matching

Tags: css, html, width

So I got two `div`s that work as my header, a navbar and a banner (a div with a background image applied to it) and right after that I got my content div where I'll put other `div`s with specific content latter on. I followed a tutorial teaching how the content to scroll over the banner and under the navbar that is fixed on the top of the page. The navbar and banner both have `width:100%` and `position:fixed`, while the content has `width:100%` and `position:relative` as instructed by the tutorial.

The problem is that the content div is off center a little to the right, in a way that the page has to scroll horizontally. And later on, while I was adding new `div`s, they all had different widths, even though they all had `width:100%`.
In the end the page was a mess, with `div`s with completely different widths.

I'll try post the code:

```
<body>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#menu_1">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu_2">Menu 2</a></a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu_3">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu_4">Menu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    <div id="banner">
        <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Bacon</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
    nav
{
    height: 100px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}
nav ul
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 40px;
}
nav li
{
    display: inline;
}
nav a:link, a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:transparent;
}
nav li a, li a:visited
{
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    width: 104px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 73px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav li a:hover
{
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #AED135;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#banner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(imgs/header_img.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    top: 100px;
    left:0px;
}
#content
{
    background:#fff;
    width:100%; 
    position:relative;
    top:610px;
    z-index:5;
    height:1000px;
}
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please, feel free to 'dumb down' your answer as much as you want! The more i read about width and positioning and stuff, the more confused I get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body by default has some pixel of margin, try adding this:

```
 body {
       margin: 0;
  }
```

Comment: I feel stupid, cause I tried margin:0 in everything, but the body!

Edit: Ok, stretching, what width:100% does afterall? Cause I'm confused. I thought it would make the div goes as far as the browser window, or it's parent width.
Now I'm not sure...

Comment: The best way to set items into the top left corner of the window is to use body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } which will work for all standards compliant browsers, Opera has Padding instead margin :P, width:100% give to the element full size based on the container(the body in your case)